# Reinforcement learning: Discounting rewards in the REINFORCE algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am looking into the REINFORCE algorithm for reinforcement learning. I am having trouble understanding how rewards should be computed.

The algorithm from Sutton & Barto:
[image]

What does G, 'return from step t' mean here?

1. Return from step t to step T-1, i.e. R_t + R_(t+1) + ... + R_(T-1)?
2. Return from step 0 to step t?, i.e. R_0 + R_1 + ... + R_(t)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does G, 'return from step t' mean here?
>
> 1. Return from step t to step T-1, i.e. R_t + R_(t+1) + ... + R_(T-1)?
> 2. Return from step 0 to step t?, i.e. R_0 + R_1 + ... + R_(t)?

Neither, but (1) is closest.

$$G_t = \sum_{i=t+1}^T R_i$$

i.e. the sum of all rewards from step $t+1$ to step $T$.

You are possibly confused because the loop for REINFORCE goes from $0$ to $T-1$. However, that makes sense due to the one step offset from return to the sum of rewards. So $G_{T-1} = R_T$ and $G_{T} = 0$ always (there is no future reward possible at the end of the episode).

Answer (score 2):

From the latest version of the book, where G is explicitly defined, and similar to [Neil Slater's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/38207/29575), 
$G_t \leftarrow$ return from step $t$ is:

$$ G_t =  \sum_{k=t+1}^T \gamma^{k-t-1}R_k $$